# Is it possible to access npm config settings from a node package's `bin` command?

Tags: node.js, shell, config

I want to add some default configuration into a shell tool that the user can override using `npm config`. It [looks like this is possible](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man7/npm-config.7.html) but this only works for `npm script`s **not** my package's binary as specified by `"bin"` below.

### Package.json

```
{
  "name": "tmp",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "node index.js"
  },
    "bin" : {
        "tmp" : "index.js"
    },
    "config": {
        "foo" : 123
    }
}
```

### index.js

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
console.log(process.env.npm_package_config_foo);
```

### My attempts

#### calling binary

*setup for this is running [`npm link`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link) in the package to make a global link to that package*

```
$ tmp
undefined
```

#### passing script to node

```
$ node ./index.js
undefined
```

#### calling as `npm script` ⫸ **only this one works**

```
$ npm test

> tmp@ test /private/tmp
> node index.js

123
```

## Question

How can I access these config values *in a way that's overridable by the user* like `npm config` allows? (To be clear I want to do it the `npm config` way; I know there are other ways to skin this particular cat.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a package called `npm-conf` with documentation at https://github.com/kevva/npm-conf.

First you need to install it:

```
npm install --save npm-conf
```

Usage is as follows:

```
const npmConf = require('npm-conf');

const conf = npmConf();

conf.get('prefix')
//=> //=> /Users/unicorn/.npm-packages

conf.get('registry')
//=> https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

If you want to get a list of all available NPM configuration options:

```
npm config list -l
```